# After the user leaves the server, how can i handle the forms?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, web-development-server

Hey there im finishing my little app which is an online platform that sells tickets for events. Im currently having some problems when the user goes out of the page. I want to get rid of the data that he has already submitted. This happens when the promoter of the event wants to create a  party, there´s two "stages" the event info and the tickets info. Im handling this with javascript´s "beforeunload" but im stuck. Could anyone give me a hint? Thank you by the way guys.

I don´t have a particular error, i would just like to get rid of the unfinished posts after the user leaves.

routes

```
    @app.route("/post/new",methods=["GET","POST"])  
    @login_required
    def new_post(): 
        #event forms
        post_form=PostForm()
        #valdiating the submission of those forms
        if post_form.validate_on_submit():
            if post_form.image_file.data:
                picture_file=save_picture(post_form.image_file.data)
            #loading to our database
            post=Post(title=post_form.title.data,content=post_form.content.data,start_dh=post_form.start_dh.data,
                       finish_dh=post_form.finish_dh.data,image_file=picture_file,author=current_user)                    
            db.session.add(post)
            db.session.commit()   
            flash("create your tickets now", "success")        
            return redirect(url_for("tickets", post_id=post.id))
        return render_template("create_post.html",title="new post",post_form=post_form,legend="New Event")
    
    #create new tickets
    @app.route("/ticket/<int:post_id>",methods=["GET","POST"])  
    @login_required
    def tickets(post_id):
        post=Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
        ticket_form=TicketForm() 
        #this variable give us the id of the last post that this user posted
        post_relation=Post.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user.id).order_by(Post.date_posted.desc()).first()
        #submission
    
        if  ticket_form.validate_on_submit(): 
            tickets=Tickets(ticket_type=ticket_form.ticket_type.data,ticket_quantity=ticket_form.ticket_quantity.data,
                             price_ticket=ticket_form.price_ticket.data, start_dh_tickets=ticket_form.start_dh_tickets.data,
                             finish_dh_tickets=ticket_form.finish_dh_tickets.data,event=post_relation)  
            db.session.add(tickets)
            db.session.commit() 
            flash("your tickets have been created","success")
            return redirect(url_for("tickets",post_id=post.id))  
        tick=Tickets.query.order_by(Tickets.post_id)   
        return render_template("create_ticket.html",title="tickets",ticket_form=ticket_form,tick=tick,post_id=post.id)
```

html/javascript

creating the tickets front end

```
<div class="content-section"> 
    <form method="POST" action="" onsubmit="setFormSubmitting()">
         {{ticket_form.hidden_tag()}}
         <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ticket_form.ticket_quantity.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                    {% if ticket_form.ticket_quantity.errors %}
                        {{ticket_form.ticket_quantity(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid")}}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in form.ticket_quantity.errors %}
                                <span> {{error}}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                    {{ ticket_form.ticket_quantity(class="form-control-label") }} 
                    {% endif %}  
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ticket_form.ticket_type.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                    {% if ticket_form.ticket_type.errors %}
                        {{ticket_form.ticket_type(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid")}}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {% for error in ticket_form.ticket_type.errors %}
                                <span> {{error}} </span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% else %}
                    {{ ticket_form.ticket_type(class="form-control-label")}} 
                    {% endif %}  
                </div>  
                <div class="form-group">
                {{ticket_form.price_ticket.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                {% if ticket_form.price_ticket.errors %}
                    {{ticket_form.price_ticket(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid")}}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in ticket_form.price_ticket.errors %}
                            <span> {{error}} </span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    {{ ticket_form.price_ticket(class="form-control-label")}} 
                {% endif %}  
                </div>  
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ticket_form.start_dh_tickets.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                    {% if ticket_form.start_dh_tickets.errors %}
                    {{ticket_form.start_dh_tickets(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid")}}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        {% for error in ticket_form.start_dh_tickets.errors %}
                            <span> {{error}} </span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    {% else %}
                    {{ ticket_form.start_dh_tickets(class="form-control-label")}} 
                    {% endif %}  
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                {{ticket_form.finish_dh_tickets.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                {% if ticket_form.finish_dh_tickets.errors %}
                    {{ticket_form.finish_dh_tickets(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid")}}
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {% for error in ticket_form.finish_dh_tickets.errors %}
                        <span> {{error}} </span>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    {{ ticket_form.finish_dh_tickets(class="form-control-label")}} 
                {% endif %}  
                </div>  
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ticket_form.submit_ticket(class="btn btn-primary")}}  
                </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form> 
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var formSubmitting = false;
    var postComplete= true;
    var setFormSubmitting = function() { formSubmitting = true; };
    var setPostComplete=function() { postComplete=false; };   

    window.onload = function() {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
         if (formSubmitting) {
             return undefined;
         }
 
         var confirmationMessage = 'you want to leave? your data will be lost';
 
         (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
         return confirmationMessage; //Gecko + Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.
     });
 };
</script>
```

creating the post frontend

```
<div class="content-section"> 
    <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="setFormSubmitting()">
         {{post_form.hidden_tag()}}
         <fieldset class="form-group">
               <legend class="border-bottom mb-4"> {{ legend }}</legend>
               <div class="form-group">
                  {{post_form.title.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                  {% if post_form.title.errors %}
                        {{post_form.title(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid")}}
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                           {% for error in post_form.title.errors %}
                              <span> {{error}}</span>
                           {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                  {% else %}
                     {{ post_form.title(class="form-control-label")}} 
                  {% endif %}  
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                  {{post_form.content.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                  {% if post_form.content.errors %}
                     {{post_form.content(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid")}}
                     <div class="invalid-feedback">
                           {% for error in post_form.content.errors %}
                              <span> {{error}} </span>
                           {% endfor %}
                     </div>
                  {% else %}
                     {{ post_form.content(class="form-control-label")}} 
                  {% endif %}  
               </div>  
               <!-- section for setting the date and hour of the event-->
               <!--  starting date hour-->
               <div class="form-group">
                  {{post_form.start_dh.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                  {% if post_form.start_dh.errors %}
                       {{post_form.start_dh(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid")}}
                       <div class="invalid-feedback">
                           {% for error in post_form.start_dh.errors %}
                              <span> {{error}}</span>
                           {% endfor %}
                       </div>
                  {% else %}
                     {{ post_form.start_dh(class="form-control-label")}} 
                  {% endif %}  
               <!-- finish -->
               <div class="form-group">
                  {{post_form.finish_dh.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                  {% if post_form.finish_dh.errors %}
                      {{post_form.finish_dh(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid")}}
                      <div class="invalid-feedback">
                           {% for error in post_form.finish_dh.errors %}
                              <span> {{error}} </span>
                           {% endfor %}
                      </div>
                  {% else %}
                     {{ post_form.finish_dh(class="form-control-label")}} 
                  {% endif %}  
               </div> 
               <!-- image -->
               <div class="form-group">
                  {{post_form.image_file.label()}}
                  {{post_form.image_file(class="form-control-file")}}
                  {% if post_form.image_file.errors %}
                           {% for error in post_form.image_file.errors %}
                              <span class="text-danger"> {{error}} </span></br>
                           {% endfor %}
                  {% endif %}  
               </div> 
               <div class="form-group">
                  {{post_form.submit_post(class="btn btn-primary")}}  
               </div>
         </fieldset>
    </form> 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var formSubmitting = false;
   var setFormSubmitting = function() { formSubmitting = true; };

   window.onload = function() {
   window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        if (formSubmitting) {
            return undefined;
        }

        var confirmationMessage = 'It looks like you have been editing something. '
                                + 'If you leave before saving, your changes will be lost.';

        (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
        return confirmationMessage; //Gecko + Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.
    });
};
</script>
```

databases

```
class Post(db.Model):
    #unique id for the user
    id= db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    #name of the event
    title= db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    #when the event was posted 
    date_posted= db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now())
    #description of the event
    content= db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    #start date and hour of the event 
    start_dh= db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    #finish date and hour of the event 
    finish_dh= db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    #image of the flyer for the post
    image_file= db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default="default.jpg")
    #linking the  post table with the user
    user_id= db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), nullable=False)
    #relation with the ticket model
    ticket=db.relationship("Tickets", backref="event", lazy=True)
    #relation ship with the customer
    customer=db.relationship("Customer", backref="party", lazy=True)
    #this is a method that declares how our class is going to be printed out 
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s" % (self.user_id,self.title,self.date_posted,self.content,self.image_file)


#data base for the tickets
class Tickets(db.Model):
    #unique id for the user
    id= db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    #name or kind of the event, this is set by the creators
    ticket_type=db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    #initial stock of the ticket
    ticket_quantity=db.Column(db.Integer,nullable=False)
    #initial price of this kind of ticket
    price_ticket=db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    #start date and hour of the event 
    start_dh_tickets=db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    #finish date and hour of the event 
    finish_dh_tickets=db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    #id of the event we have a relationship with
    post_id= db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("post.id"), nullable=False)
    #this is a method that declares how our class is going to be printed out 
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s" % (self.post_id,self.ticket_type, self.ticket_quantity,self.price_ticket,self.start_dh_tickets,self.finish_dh_tickets)
```

Comment: We aren't here to write code for you could you show us what you've tried with a minimal reproductible example?

Comment: i really have no idea what to do, i´ve been searching for information but there´s almost no information about this problem with flask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use warn message to user from browser in JavaScript:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
};
```

Or you can send data to Flask server immidiately after user changes the inputs and after click on the button, you can officially proceed them.

Comment: Yes im already using it! the problem is when i leave the website,i have to get rid of that specific data. For example if the user leaves in the second "stage" where they create the tickets, the event information is already in the data base you know? Other way if the user creates one type of tickets (an early bird only for example), and he decides to go out , i have the same issue.(assuming that he wanted x types of tickets)